# the_category() function adds up an unordered list that won't fit in a paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to figure it out how to fit the the_category() function inside a paragraph tag.
What happen is that I put everything inside a paragraph tag and won't fix everything inside one line.

here is a screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/42u82c

Here's my code for that line.

```
<p class="details">By <a href="<?php the_author_posts() ?>"><?php the_author(); ?> </a> / On <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> / In <?php the_category(); ?></p>
```

Here's the full snippet of the code for that part (loop):

```
<ul class="negative-margin">
        <li>
         <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="gray">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h1>
          <p class="details">By <a href="<?php the_author_posts() ?>"><?php the_author(); ?> </a> / On <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y'); ?> / In <?php the_category(); ?></p>
          <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
          <figure> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive')); ?></a> </figure>
          <p class="excerpt"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>
          <div class="btn-margin"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE READING >>> </a> </div>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Here's the markup being generated with that code:

```
      <ul class="negative-margin">
        <li>
                   <h1><a href="http://localhost/themewp/when-you-are-expecting-something/" class="gray">
            When you are expecting something!            </a></h1>
          <p class="details">By <a href="6">Sam Norton </a> / On July 11, 2014 / In <ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/themewp/category/life-hacks/" title="View all posts in Life Hacks" rel="category tag">Life Hacks</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/themewp/category/life-tips/" title="View all posts in Life Tips" rel="category tag">Life Tips</a></li></ul></p>
                    <figure> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/when-you-are-expecting-something/"><img width="757" height="437" src="http://localhost/themewp/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/thumb1.jpg" class="opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="thumb1" /></a> </figure>
          <p class="excerpt"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat &#8230;</p>
 </p>
          <div class="btn-margin"> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/when-you-are-expecting-something/" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE READING >>> </a> </div>
        </li>
                          <h1><a href="http://localhost/themewp/sam-is-an-idiot/" class="gray">
            What to do if you face your giants            </a></h1>
          <p class="details">By <a href="6">Sam Norton </a> / On July 10, 2014 / In <ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/themewp/category/life-tips/" title="View all posts in Life Tips" rel="category tag">Life Tips</a></li></ul></p>
                    <figure> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/sam-is-an-idiot/"><img width="757" height="437" src="http://localhost/themewp/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/thumb2.jpg" class="opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="thumb2" /></a> </figure>
          <p class="excerpt"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat &#8230;</p>
 </p>
          <div class="btn-margin"> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/sam-is-an-idiot/" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE READING >>> </a> </div>
        </li>
                          <h1><a href="http://localhost/themewp/the-only-thing-you-need-in-life/" class="gray">
            The only thing you need in life            </a></h1>
          <p class="details">By <a href="6">Sam Norton </a> / On July 10, 2014 / In <ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://localhost/themewp/category/life-hacks/" title="View all posts in Life Hacks" rel="category tag">Life Hacks</a></li></ul></p>
                    <figure> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/the-only-thing-you-need-in-life/"><img width="757" height="437" src="http://localhost/themewp/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/thumb1.jpg" class="opacity-hover box-layer img-responsive wp-post-image" alt="thumb1" /></a> </figure>
          <p class="excerpt"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat &#8230;</p>
 </p>
          <div class="btn-margin"> <a href="http://localhost/themewp/the-only-thing-you-need-in-life/" class="btn btn-primary">CONTINUE READING >>> </a> </div>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the markup generated by the the_category() function.  It's clearly outputting block level elements (or inline elements styled as block level elements).  Show use the HTML code generated.  EDIT: Sorry, you say in the title that it's an unordered list.

Comment: Thanks! I already updated the above information please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `the_category()` function is outputting an unordered list, you need to make the items of the list inline and add some right margin to the items so there will be some spacing between them.

```
p.details ul.post-categories li { display:inline; margin-right:10px; }
```

That's the most basic way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried adding this: p.details ul li { display:inline; margin-right:10px; } on my CSS but it still wont fix the position of the the_category() function.

Comment: It *should* work.  Try inspecting the UL/LI elements in your browser's developer tools (preferably Chrome) and see if the new style is being applied or if there's some other style overriding it.

Comment: Here's what I did added p.details{ display:inline;}
ul.post-categories li { display:inline; margin-right:10px; } in a seperate lines and it works! Thanks for the answer! Really help!

Comment: Yeah, In my answer I forgot to add an inline style to the UL element as well.  Maybe instead of doing p.details{ display:inline;}, try doing p.details ul { display:inline; } - I think it's the more correct way :-)